# Clifford index of curves on a surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose C is a smooth curve lying on a smooth surface X such that C belongs to |nH|, where H is an ample divisor on X. How to calculate the Clifford index Cliff(C) ?

Comment: There is a paper of Green and Lazarsfeld in which they show that the Clifford index of a curve is constant in the case you mention if $X$ is a K-3 surface.  I've never heard anyone suggest, and off-hand I can't think of any reason why, this is true on an arbitrary surface.  My guess is that $P^3$ should already provide counterexamples.  Namely take a curve $C$, then for $n>>0$ it should lie on a hypersurface that depends only on the gross numerical invariants of $C$ and not it's Clifford index. 